# XCode 6 GUI Not Updating

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using XCode 6 to make a simple calculator using Swift. Anyway, I compiled the code with the initial GUI and it works. However when I change the positioning of some buttons, it does not show up in the compiled app running on iOS simulator. Does anyone know what should be done?

Also, I've changed the code as well, and the code is updated. Ie, pressing button 1 will show 1 in the main textbox, but the interesting thing is the position of the button, which I have changed, still remains in the same position I set it to be initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you changing the positions of the buttons? If you're doing this by setting frames in code, and your original GUI is laid out in a storyboard, then you're probably fighting against auto layout.

Your storyboard layout will be driven by constraints, which determine the size and position of all the elements of your GUI. Setting a frame manually doesn't change these constraints, so the layout engine resets everything.

Either turn off auto layout (bad idea, since you now have to cope with every screen size manually) or move your buttons by adjusting your constraints.